# Bootstrap row height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to modify some template code for a eCommerce site which is based on bootstrap and react and I am new to bootstrap. I ran into a container which had two rows and I would like to reduce the height of the row. What is the best way to approach that?

Comment: Please post your relevant code and your attemps. Read [mcve]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I believe this is the answer you are looking for with regards to Bootstrap Conventions.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#small-table

With regards to including the bootstrap styles use these CDN's they always work for me. https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap

You only need the CSS and the JavaScript — you don't need all of the links.

Alternatively you can set the height of the divs to whatever you want through the use of a `CSS` class.

```
.custom-row-class {
    height: 10px;
    /*height: 10px !important;*/
    /*etc...*/
}
```

```
<div class="custom-row-class">
this is my div  
</div>
```

If your height style is not pulling through you can try overriding the style for with the !important tag. I added a commented out piece in the CSS for you with an !important Tag.

Comment: As this link can provide an answer (are you sure he use bootstrap 4?) it's better provide a little explanation for bootstrap because the link can change or may become unreachable.

Comment: Well I added a link for conventional method and added basic code for a simple method. :)